# My code doesn't show the email name when logged in

Tags: php, codeigniter, login-script

**logins.php**

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $email= $_POST['email'];
    $Password= $_POST['pass'];

     if ($email && $Password){
        $connect =mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die ("Couldn't connect!"); 
        mysql_select_db("formbatch7") or die ("couldn't find db");
        $query = mysql_query("select * FROM logintr where email='$email'");

        $numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);



        if ($numrows!=0)
        {
            while ($row= mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
            {
                $dbemail = $row['email'];
                $dbpassword = $row['Password'];
            }
            //Chack to see if they match
            if ($email==$dbemail and $Password==$dbpassword)
            {
                echo "you are in! <a href='trl.php'>click</a> hear to enter the page";
                $_session['email']=$email;
            }
            else
                echo "incorrect password!";
        }
        else

        die ("That user dosent Exist");
        //echo"<script>alert('details not correct') </script>";



    }
     else

        die ("please evter the user name and password");
?>
```

After typing the correct password the "click" link (trl.php) is not showing the email name, it only shows "welcome,!"

**this is the trl.php code:**

```
<?php 
    session_start();
    echo "welcome, ".$_session['email']."!";
?>
```

Comment: CodeIgniter has it's own database.php config file and library it will save you using  `$connect =mysql_connect` http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/connecting.html you can autoload it. And also codeigniter has a session library http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html

Answer (score 0):

Please change your `$_session['email']` to `$_SESSION['email']`.

PHP uses a set of predefined variables. [PHP Predefined variables](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.php)

We need to use them as it is without changing their cases.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks @Object Manipulator